# Sort two columns Excel

Tags: excel, sorting, rows

I have two different columns on Excel. 
I want to create a script that will sort Column F, (Have a header) and will sort Column B based on where Column F's sort worked out. (Without affecting any other columns however!)

So if I have

```
    ColB       ColF
 1. Cat        2
 2. Mouse      1
 3. Dog        3
```

The sort will give me

```
    ColB       ColF
 1. Mouse        1
 2. Cat          2
 3. Dog          3
```

How can I do this? 
I tried recording a macro of just sorting it out, but I get an error saying "The command cannot be performed with multiple selections, Click a single range and try again"

Comment: Is it a requirement that the two columns be non-contiguous? You can sort multiple columns so long as it's a single selection, and not multiple columns. I.E. either move B/F next to each other, or select B:F, and select sort by F.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of is to temporarily copy over your two columns into a vertical look-up table with column F on the left.

Then sort your column F and update column D with VLookup with the format like:

```
=VLOOKUP(F1,[Temp Table Range],2,FALSE)
```

Then if you want to delete the temp table, just make sure you replace column D's formulas with values.

You can do all of this with a macro it just has several steps. I could write it for you, but that isn't really what Stackoverflow is about.

Have fun. :-)

Comment: That's a start, I'll look into working with that :D