# sort ascending column B and change matched column F vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

how can I sort ascending column B and accordingly change column F? (column B and column F have a correspondence). I don't want to sort columns A,C,D,E or all other columns.

Here is my code, but this sorts only column B and columns A or C (the columns close to the column I want to sort).

```
    Range("B1").CurrentRegion.Select

    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("B1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/451225/sorting-two-non-adjacent-columns-without-affecting-any-other-column or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570650/sort-two-columns-excel

Comment: Thnks, but I needed vba code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have data in rows **2** thru **21** then:

```
Sub SortIt()
    Dim i As Long, J As Long, Low As Long, Hi As Long
    Dim Temp As Variant
    Low = 2
    Hi = 21
      J = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
      Do While J > 0
        For i = Low To Hi - J
          If Cells(i, 2) > Cells(i + J, 2) Then
            Temp = Cells(i, 2)
            Cells(i, 2) = Cells(i + J, 2)
            Cells(i + J, 2) = Temp
            Temp = Cells(i, 6)
            Cells(i, 6) = Cells(i + J, 6)
            Cells(i + J, 6) = Temp
          End If
        Next i

        For i = Hi - J To Low Step -1
          If Cells(i, 2) > Cells(i + J, 2) Then
            Temp = Cells(i, 2)
            Cells(i, 2) = Cells(i + J, 2)
            Cells(i + J, 2) = Temp
            Temp = Cells(i, 6)
            Cells(i, 6) = Cells(i + J, 6)
            Cells(i + J, 6) = Temp
          End If
        Next i
        J = J \ 2
      Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Gary's Student, your sorting algorithm works perfectly. Thanks a lot! I really appreaciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can move the column:

```
Columns("F:F").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

Range("B:C").Select

Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("B1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("G:G").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

Sort and move again.

Or build a proper Sort...